# Pass function as value for another function

Tags: java, function, loops

I've been trying to find out how to do this, but can't seem to find a good result.

What I'm trying to do is pass a function in another function, and then get the result (in the actual code it would be in a loop, so the point is to get the value as it updates even if the value is private).

So the code (pseudocode)

```
String myFunction(Function otherFunction) {
    return otherFunction.call();
}

String anotherFunction() {
    return "Hello World!";
}
```

Would make it so running `myFunction(anotherFunction);` would return "Hello World!"

Comment: (1) You have to use `YourClass::anotherFunction` or `someInstance::anotherFunction`, (2) your function is not really a function, but a `Supplier` as it takes no parameter.

Comment: You can actually pass your method as a Runnable and then use the run method to execute it.
`myFunction(() -> anotherFunction())`

Comment: @Melron That works for calling functions, but is a void. I specifically need to get the output.

Comment: Use `Callable<String>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem using the approach with interfaces as shown below (which is more reasonable).

```
interface MyFunction {
    String call();
}

class AnotherFunction implements MyFunction {
    @Override
    public String call() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static String myFunction(MyFunction otherFunction) {
        return otherFunction.call();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFunction anotherFunction = new AnotherFunction();
        String result = myFunction(anotherFunction);
        System.out.println(result); // "Hello World!"
    }
}
```

Or you can also use the java.util.function package as demonstrated below.

```
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class Main {

    public static String myFunction(Supplier<String> otherFunction) {
        return otherFunction.get();
    }

    public static String anotherFunction() {
        return "Hello World!";
 }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String result = myFunction(Main::anotherFunction);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java is fully typed. Hence, `Function` as an argument just isn't going to fly: How many arguments does this function take, and what are its types? Does this function return anything, and if it does, what type does that have? `Function` doesn't cover any of that. Hence, this doesn't work.

Java has taken a somewhat unique approach to the notion of making code referencable (i.e. "passing functions around"). You **first** describe the precise thing that you want to accept (not *just* in terms of the # of types of the parameters and the return type, but also more semantically: You give it a name). You do this in a so-called functional interface - that's an interface that has only 1 method (after stripping out anything `Object` itself already defines, and anything with a `default` impl). You can annotate them with `@FunctionalInterface`; - such interfaces (with 1 method) that aren't annotated as such are still functional interfaces; the annotation simply serves as compiler-checked documentation (in that if it isn't one, `javac` will refuse to compile it).

So, let's make one. For this hypothetical scenario, we have a simple calculator, and we want to represent the action that is to be performed when someone presses a function button. This is a bit of an odd calculator; it only deals with integers.

This would be in *your* code:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface IntCalculatorOp {
  public int calculate(int a, int b);
}
```

You could fancy this up and introduce the notion of unary and binary operations, but let's keep it simple as this is just an example to show how all this works; this calculator only does binary operations.

You can now define the calculator itself:

```java
class IntCalculator {
    private final Map<String, IntCalculatorOp> ops = new HashMap<>();
    
    public void registerOp(String button, IntCalculatorOp op) {
        this.ops.put(button, op);
    }
    
    // I wouldn't use Stack in a serious project - just an example!
    private Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
    
    public void enterNumber(int num) {
        stack.push(num);
    }
    
    public void pressButton(String button) {
        int b = stack.pop();
        int a = stack.pop();
        stack.push(ops.get(button).calculate(a, b));
    }
    
    public int get() {
        return stack.pop();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var calc = new IntCalculator();
        calc.registerOp("+", (a, b) -> a + b);
        calc.registerOp("*", (a, b) -> a * b);
        
        calc.enterNumber(5);
        calc.enterNumber(2);
        calc.pressButton("+");
        System.out.println("5 + 2 = " + calc.get());
        calc.enterNumber(4);
        calc.enterNumber(3);
        calc.pressButton("*");
        System.out.println("4 * 3 = " + calc.get());
    }
}
```

A few key aspects:

- Lambda syntax (those `(a, b) -> a + b` things) **require** that you put them in a context where the compiler can figure out which functional interface they are supposed to be. The second arg of the `registerOp` method is `IntCalculatorOp` which is a functional interface, and that's why this works. You can't write `Object o = (a, b) -> a + b;` because that's not sufficient context for the compiler to guess that you wanted an IntCalculatorOp there.
- The `java.util.function` package has a few generalized function types. These are appropriate **only** if you have a highly general concept, such as 'do a thing to all things in this list' (e.g. java's own `Stream` has methods that take such arguments). If you can more specifically define semantically what a thing does (such as 'it represents a button on my integers-only calculator'), you should make a type for it. Java is nominal and typed, work with the language, don't try to fight what it's about.
- `Function` *can* be used, but you need to add generics or the compiler can't know what the types must be. `Function<String, Integer>`, for example (lambdas that are passed to methods that take that type as argument could for example take the form of `String::length`, or `x -> x.length()` - its a function that accepts 1 param of type String and returns a value of type Integer). `ToIntFunction<String>` is probably the better fit, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just returning a value then why not use a `Supplier<T>`.  Then you can return the appropriate type.

```
String result1 = myFunction(this::anotherFunction);
int result2 = myFunction(this::anotherFunction2);
System.out.println(result1);
System.out.println(result2);
```

prints

```
Hello, World
23
```

```
public  <T> T myFunction(Supplier<T> otherFunction) {
    return otherFunction.get();
}

public String anotherFunction() {
     return "Hello, World";
}
public Integer anotherFunction2() {
    return 23;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this (thanks @Kayaman and @Melron)

Here's how it works, with those same 2 functions:

```
String myFunction(Callable<Object> otherFunction) { // It's Callable<Object> because I want to be able to accept any type as the output - you can also use Callable<String> to accept only functions that output Strings.
    try {
        return otherFunction.call();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

String anotherFunction() {
    return "Hello World!";
}
```

And for calling it, you would do `myFunction(() -> anotherFunction())`.

Comment: Check my answer for an alternative to `Callable`.  No need to specify return type as the compiler figures it out.